# Set fonts dynamically in jasper

Tags: jasper-reports

I use jasper reports as internationalization contains en_us & fa. So I want to set fonts in JRXML dynamically, but I don’t know how to get fonts in JRXML from application. I will be glad if help me for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `So I want to set fonts in JRXML dynamically` - Are you talking about *Java* code? You can look at [Conditional Styles](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/index.html#conditionalstyles)